# Why user@hostname color changes after sourcing a file?

Tags: bash, prompt

I noticed whenever I source a file, the color of user@hostname changes:

[image]

Why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because it loads the user setings specified in your `/etc/bash.bashrc` file. And the prompt settings may be different from your actual terminal context. For more details have a look at the other upvoted answers. :)

Answer (score 7):

This is because /etc/bash.bashrc sets a new value for your prompt:

```
# set a fancy prompt (non-color, overwrite the one in /etc/profile)
# but only if not SUDOing and have SUDO_PS1 set; then assume smart user.
if ! [ -n "${SUDO_USER}" -a -n "${SUDO_PS1}" ]; then
  PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
```

Answer (score 7):

The appearance of the *prompt* (the `user@host` thing) is controlled by the variable `PS1`.
Probably you have something like

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
```

in your `~/.bashrc` file. The weird `\[\033[00m\]` etc. characters are used for colouring the prompt.
`\u` is the username (`h4ck3r`), `\h` is the hostname (`h4ck3rE780`) and `\w` is the current working 
directory (`~` which denotes your HOME directory).

When you source `/etc/bash.bashrc` then the variable `PS1` gets set to some other value (without colours)
and you get a different prompt. It's quite simple.

Try

```
PS1='user=\u, host=\h, directory=\w $'
```

in a terminal window and see the result. Sourcing `/etc/bash.bashrc` doesn't do anything different (besides the actual parameters).